# How can you cast a 2 dimensional array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, initialization

My brain has gone a lot fuzzy just recently and I can't for the life of me remember why the following C code:

```
char a[3][3] = { "123", "456", "789" };
char **b = a;
```

Generates the following warning:

```
warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
```

Could someone please explain this for me.

Thank you.

Comment: Please, notice that "123" in your declaration isn't string anymore because you truncated \0. "123" as string contains 4 chars, not 3.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
char (*b)[3] = a;
```

This declares `b` as a pointer to char arrays of size 3. Note that this is not the same as `char *b[3]`, which declares `b` as an array of 3 char pointers.

Also note that `char *b = a` is wrong and still emits the same warning as `char **b = a`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
   char a[3][3] = { {'1','2','3'}, {'4','5','6'}, {'7','8','9' }};
   char *b = &a[0][0];
```

Since, a is character array of arrays you need to initialize them as a character.

Answer (score 0):

That is right.
`a` is a pointer.

`char *b` defines a pointer to char.

`char **b` defines a pointer to pointer to char.

Comment: `a` is not a pointer; `a` is an array. An unqualified statement saying that `a` is a pointer is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that ** is not statically allocated.

you could accomplish this simple version with the following:

```
char a[3][3] = {"123", "456", "789"};
char *b[3] = {a[0], a[1], a[2]};
```

Answer (score -1):

`a` is still a pointer to a char:

```
char* b = a;
```

Comment: Yup that's it.  It's obviously too late at night for me to be coding.

Comment: This is not correct. `a` decays to a pointer to its first element; `a` is an array of `char[3]`; a pointer to its first element has type `char (*)[3]` not `char*`. This pointer initialization generates exactly the same incompatible pointer type warning as the original code.